# How can I generate random number in specific range in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, random

I want to generate random number in a specific range. (Ex. Range Between 65 to 80)

I try as per below code, but it is not very use full. It also returns the value greater then max. value(greater then 80).

```
Random r = new Random();
int i1 = (r.nextInt(80) + 65);
```

How can I generate random number between a range?

Comment: With [Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45687695/8583692) you can do this: `val r = (0..10).random()`

Comment: You can write `val randomNumber = (min..max).random()` where `min` and `max` are the edges of the specified range. Refer [Kotlin – Generate a Random Number in specific Range](https://kotlinandroid.org/kotlin/kotlin-generate-a-random-number-in-specific-range/)

Answer (score 524, accepted):

```
Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(80 - 65) + 65;
```

This gives a random integer between 65 (inclusive) and 80 (exclusive), one of `65,66,...,78,79`.

Comment: it won't work for negative numbers

Comment: If you need a negative number, use this and multiply by -1. You need a float, I think.

Comment: @Sirens: He could even generate two more numbers, then count differente between them (it can be negative or positive number ;)), and finaly multiply the original random number ;)

Comment: simpler as possible: int myRandomInt = new Random().nextInt(80 - 65) + 65;

Comment: I've been writing Java in one way or another for about 8 years and I still copy and paste this code whenever I need it, cheers 

Comment: @TomeeNS that would weaken the randomness .. these arent actual random numbers, dont forget.

Comment: this is just pseudo-random!

Answer (score 308):

```
int min = 65;
int max = 80;

Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

Note that `nextInt(int max)` returns an `int` between 0 inclusive and max exclusive. Hence the `+1`.