# how can i get questions randomly from different json files

Tags: android, json

I am new to Android. I am doing small quiz application. I have 5 sets of JSON file like .txt files. Each set consist of 30 questions.

My requirement is select 3 questions from each JSON set. Totaly i need to display 15 questions from 5 sets. How can i take questions from all sets ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Parse your 5 files to 5 diffrent `ArrayList` of `String` questions and then choose randomly 3 question from each `ArrayList`. to get an idea how to parse `Json` files you can take a look at this blog post I wrote, the example there is much more complicated but you will get the point:

[Parsing Json Files](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=746)

and to choose them randomly take a look at the `Random` class and at this post:

[How can I generate random number in specific range in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029495/how-can-i-generate-random-number-in-specific-range-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the TextFiles into a String
2. Parse the String into a [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)
3. Using the JSONObject's methods, fill an Array or a List with the questions. 
   As you want to extract 5 questions for each file, you will need a List/Array per file.
4. Using random numbers (See [Random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-number-in-a-range-with-java)), extract the questions at the random index.

Comment: Probably because we both answered it at nearly the same time.