# How can I generate a random number in a certain range?

Tags: android, random, numbers, range, generator

How can I create an app that generates a random number in Android using Eclipse and then show the result in a `TextView` field? The random number has to be in a range selected by the user. So, the user will input the max and min of the range, and then I will output the answer.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

To extend what Rahul Gupta said:

You can use Java function `int random = Random.nextInt(n)`.
This returns a random `int` in the range `[0, n-1]`.

I.e., to get the range `[20, 80]` use:

```
final int random = new Random().nextInt(61) + 20; // [0, 60] + 20 => [20, 80]
```

To generalize more:

```
final int min = 20;
final int max = 80;
final int random = new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

Comment: can you take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46638945/6144372 It is related to `Random.nextInt(n)`.

Answer (score 25):

```
Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(45 - 28) + 28;
```

**This gives a random integer between 28 (inclusive) and 45 (exclusive), one of 28,29,...,43,44.**

Comment: answer copied from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6029519/6144372 
At least consider giving credit to the original answer.

Answer (score 12):

Also, from API level 21 this is possible:

```
int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max);
```

Comment: Returns the same number too frequently here. Bad experience!

Comment: agree with @1111161171159459134

Comment: yes, indeed, I don't use this anymore either. The random class is better

Answer (score 10):

```
/**
* min and max are to be understood inclusively
*/
public static int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
    return (new Random()).nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

" the user is the one who select max no and min no ?"
What do you mean by this line ?

You can use java function `int random = Random.nextInt(n)`. This returns a random int in range[0, n-1]).

and you can set it in your textview using the `setText()` method

Comment: Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method nextInt(int) from the type Random

Comment: int random = Random.nextInt(5);

Comment: Your error is not because of my code. Show the class in which you have written this code. This error usually comes in a static method

Comment: its not static method and i used in asyn task()

Comment: Post your code in which you are getting this issue and the line number also

Answer (score 2):

So you would want the following:

```
int random;
int max;
int min;
```

...somewhere in your code put the method to get the min and max from the user when they click submit and then use them in the following line of code:

```
random = Random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
```

This will set random to a random number between the user selected min and max.
Then you will do:

```
TextView.setText(random.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

**Random Number Generator in Android**
If you want to know about random number generator in android then you should read this article till end. Here you can get all information about random number generator in android. [Random Number Generator in Android](https://skillmaking.com/how-to-create-random-number-generator-in-android/)

You should use this code in your java file.

```
Random r = new Random();
                    int randomNumber = r.nextInt(100);
                    tv.setText(String.valueOf(randomNumber));
```

I hope this answer may helpful for you. If you want to read more about this article then you should read this article. [Random Number Generator](https://skillmaking.com/how-to-create-random-number-generator-in-android/)

Comment: (From Review: The second link you posted is completely broken. Please edit your answer and either fix it OR remove it. Thank you.)

Answer (score 2):

Below code will help you to generate random numbers between two numbers in the given range:

```
private void generateRandomNumbers(int min, int max) {
    // min & max will be changed as per your requirement. In my case, I've taken min = 2 & max = 32

    int randomNumberCount = 10;

    int dif = max - min;
    if (dif < (randomNumberCount * 3)) {
        dif = (randomNumberCount * 3);
    }

    int margin = (int) Math.ceil((float) dif / randomNumberCount);
    List<Integer> randomNumberList = new ArrayList<>();

    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumberCount; i++) {
        int range = (margin * i) + min; // 2, 5, 8

        int randomNum = random.nextInt(margin);
        if (randomNum == 0) {
            randomNum = 1;
        }

        int number = (randomNum + range);
        randomNumberList.add(number);
    }
    Collections.sort(randomNumberList);
    Log.i("generateRandomNumbers", "RandomNumberList: " + randomNumberList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use If `Random`. For example, this generates a random number between 75 to 100.

```
final int random = new Random().nextInt(26) + 75;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below function

```
public int generate_random(int min, int max) {
    return new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put that code in your java file

```
public static int generateRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
    return new Random().nextInt((max- min) + 1) + min;
}
```