# How to generate random numbers and distribute them randomly to some buttons?

Tags: java, android, random

I am rookie in android programming and want to generate some numbers randomly in a specific range. Provided that, the sum of two of them equals a certain number, I wrote the following in `onCreate()` and `onRestart` to re-generate them every time the activity starts, but it doesn't work every time:

```
//i1,i2,i3..... are initialized in the class body as integers

      do {
        i1=r.nextInt((30-1)+1)+1;
        i2=r.nextInt((30-1)+1)+1;
        i3=r.nextInt((30-1)+1)+1;
        i4=r.nextInt((30-1)+1)+1;
        i5=r.nextInt((30-1)+1)+1;
        i6=r.nextInt((30-1)+1)+1;
        i7=r.nextInt((30-1)+1)+1;
        i8=r.nextInt((30-1)+1)+1;
        i9=r.nextInt((30-1)+1)+1;
    }  while (i1+i2!=25);

    String[] str= {String.valueOf(i1),String.valueOf(i2),String.valueOf(i3),
            String.valueOf(i4),String.valueOf(i5),String.valueOf(i6),
            String.valueOf(i7),String.valueOf(i8),String.valueOf(i9)};

    btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btn5= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    btn6= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    btn7= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
    btn8= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);
    btn9= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn7.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn8.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn9.setOnClickListener(this);

    // this is the code which distribute the numbers randomly to the buttons:
    btn1.setText(str[random.nextInt(str.length)]);
    btn2.setText(str[random.nextInt(str.length)]);
    btn3.setText(str[random.nextInt(str.length)]);
    btn4.setText(str[random.nextInt(str.length)]);
    btn5.setText(str[random.nextInt(str.length)]);
    btn6.setText(str[random.nextInt(str.length)]);
    btn7.setText(str[random.nextInt(str.length)]);
    btn8.setText(str[random.nextInt(str.length)]);
    btn9.setText(str[random.nextInt(str.length)]);
```

Sometimes there are really two numbers of them whose sum is '25' but sometimes no, and I don't understand the reason.
And, I want to know how to generate those numbers without repeating.

Comment: can you create the buttons dynamically?

Comment: Can you explain more ? @RushiAyyappa

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Random class`like this

```
  final int total=25;
  int otherno;
  Random num =new Random();
    int mo=num.nextInt(24);
  otherno= total-mo;
```

this will generate two no `mo` and `otherno` with sum equal 25 and it will be generated at a random if you want multiple pair just put this in for loop .I am using final key word as the total is not going to change for any no. [for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029495/how-can-i-generate-random-number-in-specific-range-in-android),amout [random no ex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049747/how-can-i-generate-random-number-in-range-in-android-and-show-it-in-a-textview-f)

Comment: Good solution, but I think he would want to use num.nextInt(25) to get numbers between 0 and 25

Comment: See the update answer @BrianPipa and Mohammad Abubeih

Answer (score 0):

In your activity.xml: take a linearLayout and id it as ll_main.

In your onCreate()

```
       ArrayList<Integer> al_list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
          //generate random number
         ll.removeAllViews();
          for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
              {

                  int num=getRandomNumberInRange(0,10);
                  if(num!=-1){
                 al_list.add(num); 
                 Button btn=new Button(this);
                 btn.setId(num);
                 btn.setText(num+"");
                 ll_main.addView(btn);                      
                  }


              }

    private  int getRandomNumberInRange(int min, int max) {

          if (min >= max) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("max must be greater than min");
    }

    Random r = new Random();
int num=r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
     if(al_list.contains(num))
       {
        getRandomNumberInRange(0,10);
     return -1;
        }
      else{
      return num;
      }  
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't give two numbers whose sum is "25" ,or any other number,

Comment: Please change random num logic..but button logic will work

Comment: Will this give ,at least, two numbers which is their sum equals = ... ??