# Randomizing Strings associated with an Integer in a Map?

Tags: java, string, random, dictionary, integer

I want to randomly be able to return a person's name in a map using the method `randomizeName`(int group); I want it to randomize the Strings in a Map called people.
Here is how people looks:

```
public Map<Integer, String> people = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

There are three groups in people, 1, 2, and 3.
There are nine Strings in this HashMap, each associated with a group:
`Greg, George, Fred, Marie, Ann, Julie, Alfred, Bob, and Julian.`
How do I return a randomized String only in group one, for example.

So instead of it randomizing the Strings in the entire Map, how do I make it only randomize the people in group one`(Greg, George and Fred)`?

Here is the method:

```
public String randomizeName(int group){
//Enter Code Here
}
```

Comment: You need t make an effort to solve the problem yourself before posting.  Also, your question is very unclear. What output do you want to see?

Comment: How are you keeping track of what group people are in? You understand that `people.put(1, "Greg"); people.put(1, "George");` won't store both entries?

Comment: Yes, and also can you please post what the key for your hash map is? What does that integer correspond to?

Comment: Maybe a different design would be better: A class which is a Group and contains a List of all members, and outside another List with all groups. What about it?

Comment: Names in a Map are not random. What do you mean by "random" Strings?

Comment: You need either a Map<Integer, List<String>> or a multimap from e.g., Guava. Try building each piece individually, such as creating the map, finding out how many names are in a group, calculating a random number in the desired range, and getting the name from a group at a given index. Those are the pieces you need.

Answer (score 0):

I will help you with following details...

First I think you need to create a proper hash map, your map can contain only single person per group id

Task for you : change the map such that per key(group id 1, 2 or 3) it can contain more number of member names

second you can use random number generation within a range and use it to decide what name you want to send refer [How can I generate random number in specific range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029495/how-can-i-generate-random-number-in-specific-range-in-android)

Task for you : code such a way that for different random number you can send different user name

Answer (score 0):

Mean you want

```
public String randomizeName(int group){
//Enter Code Here
}
```

should return any String of group one that is (Greg, George and Fred). Right?
If yes then you can use Math library and use random function which return a double variable. 0<=value>=1 ie value would be either 0 or greater and 1 or lesser. So you can make condition. if math.random is 0 then Greg and if math.random 1 then George and if (0math.random) then Fred. You can refer this link as well http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_random.htm