# Cannot resolve methods in Android app for game of craps

Tags: java, android, methods

I am creating a simple dice rolling application.
I am getting this error:

> cannot resolve method for my nextInt() method and valueOf() method.

I have declared the `myResults` variable as an `Integer` so I am not sure why I am getting this error. Currently the application should roll a die and return the value. I cannot get to the rest of the logic until I resolve this error. I want to make sure that I can at least get this part running before I continue. The end goal is to roll two die and return the sum of both but I have only coded for one die roll at the moment. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        // my variables
        TextView mText;
        ImageButton mButton;
        int myResults;
        String output;

        // function that runs on Start Up
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results);
            mButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.roll);

            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    myResults = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis().nextInt(6)+1);
                    rollDice();
                    mText.setText(String.valueOF(myResults));
                }
            });
        }

        public void rollDice()
        {
            switch (myResults)
            {
                case 1:
                    mButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.die1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.die2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.die3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    mButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.die4);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    mButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.die5);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    mButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.die6);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Once this issue is resolved I would like some guidance on factoring in the second die into myResults. But resolving the methods first would be great.

Error at:

```
myResults = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis().nextInt(6)+1);
rollDice();
mText.setText(String.valueOF(myResults));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is,

**First:**

```
myResults = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt(6)+1;
```

**Second:**

```
mText.setText(String.valueOf(myResults));
```

Try this way.

Answer (score 3):

You placed the `)` in the wrong place.

```
myResults = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis().nextInt(6)+1);
```

Should be

```
myResults = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt(6)+1;
```

Answer (score 2):

System.currentTimeMillis() returns a `long` which is a primitive and hence doesn't have any member `nextInt(...)`.

`valueOF()` << I think your problem here is the capitalised 'F'.

On a somewhat related note I wouldn't include the dice logic in the activity code. A better approach that follows the principles of OOP and MVC architecture would be to extract the dice logic into a separate class and call that from the activity.

Answer (score 2):

`String.valueOf()` is incorrectly capitalised in your code (`String.valueOF()`).

You are also using the `Random` `nextInt()` method incorrectly. `System.currentTimeInMillis()` returns a `long` value, whereas `nextInt()` requires a `Random` object. The correct way to use `nextInt()` is demonstrated in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029495/how-can-i-generate-random-number-in-specific-range-in-android).

```
Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(80 - 65) + 65;
```