# Distribute buttons randomly on predetermined positions in an Android App

Tags: android, button, random

I wanna set 3 Buttons horziontal side by side. If I start the app the buttons should be in a different position. How can I do this? :) Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you please share what exactly you want to do?  You want to set 3 buttons side by side  and then you are saying it should be in different position? What does that mean?

Comment: I am sorry. I want 3 buttons that change their predefined position at random among each other. I hope you understand. :/ For exemple: button1 is on the right, button2 in the middle and button3 on the right. Another possible arrangement would be button2 - button3 - button1...You understand? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnCreateView get the button id of button eg first button

Button myButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.);
myButton1.setX();
myButton1.setY();

Comment: thx but how can I do this random?  so that every start the buttons are on a different position. For example by first start:button1 - button2 - button3; second start: button2 -button3 - button1. You understand ;)?

Comment: give button ides appended by numbers like button+x, and generate x randomly as follows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029495/how-can-i-generate-random-number-in-specific-range-in-android