# How can I get a random number in Kotlin?

Tags: random, kotlin, jvm

A generic method that can return a random integer between 2 parameters like ruby does with `rand(0..n)`.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 691, accepted):

My suggestion would be an [extension](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) function on [IntRange](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-closed-range/index.html) to create randoms like this: `(0..10).random()`

### TL;DR Kotlin >= 1.3, one Random for all platforms

As of  1.3, Kotlin comes with its own multi-platform Random generator. It is described in this [KEEP](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/random.md). The extension described below is now [part of the Kotlin standard library](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/random.html#random), simply use it like this:

```
val rnds = (0..10).random() // generated random from 0 to 10 included
```

---

#### Kotlin < 1.3

Before 1.3, on the JVM we use `Random` or even `ThreadLocalRandom` if we're on JDK > 1.6.

```
fun IntRange.random() = 
       Random().nextInt((endInclusive + 1) - start) + start
```

Used like this:

```
// will return an `Int` between 0 and 10 (incl.)
(0..10).random()
```

If you wanted the function only to return `1, 2, ..., 9` (`10` not included), use a range constructed with [`until`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html):

```
(0 until 10).random()
```

If you're working with JDK > 1.6, use [`ThreadLocalRandom.current()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) instead of `Random()`.

**KotlinJs and other variations**

For kotlinjs and other use cases which don't allow the usage of `java.util.Random`, see [this alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49507413/8073652).

Also, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47863752/8073652) for variations of my suggestion. It also includes an extension function for random `Char`s.

Comment: I assume this also uses Java's `java.util.Random`?

Comment: @SimonForsberg Indeed. I added another answer which doesn't make use of it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49507413/8073652

Comment: There's also a proposal here to add a Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator (CSPRNG) here:
https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/184

Comment: `val rnds = (0..10).random()` 
actually generates 0 through 10 including __10__  and __0__.  
https://pl.kotl.in/1o8LyD1Dc

Comment: It works although return same number for every call

Comment: Lets say you want to have 10 digit number. It would create a gigantic  list in the memory and just pick one. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @RobAnderson no, it would just create an [`IntRange`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/), which is just a wrapper type with 2 int fields representing the start and end of the range (i.e. no list is created.) Then `IntRange.random` will call [`nextInt(IntRange)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/next-int.html), which is just a wrapper for `nextInt` from `start` to `endInclusive`

Answer (score 51):

Generate a random integer between `from`(inclusive) and `to`(exclusive)

```
import java.util.Random

val random = Random()

fun rand(from: Int, to: Int) : Int {
    return random.nextInt(to - from) + from
}
```

Comment: If you want to get a couple of ranged random `Int`s, you can use [Random#int(size,from,to)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-) instead in [tag:java-8].

Comment: This solution doesn't work on Javascript / Native Kotlin. Perhaps it could be cool to make a more generic method to do this. :)

Comment: @ValentinMichalak you can try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49507413/8073652

Answer (score 38):

As of kotlin 1.2, you could write:

`(1..3).shuffled().last()`

Just be aware it's big O(n), but for a small list (especially of unique values) it's alright :D

Comment: this one is useful for kotlin-native

Answer (score 18):

In Kotlin SDK >=1.3 you can do it like

```
import kotlin.random.Random

val number = Random.nextInt(limit)
```

Comment: easy one. no need to write extension function

Answer (score 14):

You can create an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) similar to [`java.util.Random.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) but one that takes an [`IntRange`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/) instead of an `Int` for its bound:

```
fun Random.nextInt(range: IntRange): Int {
    return range.start + nextInt(range.last - range.start + 1)
}
```

You can now use this with any [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) instance:

```
val random = Random()
println(random.nextInt(5..9)) // prints 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9
```

If you don't want to have to manage your own `Random` instance then you can define a convenience method using, for example, [`ThreadLocalRandom.current()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#current--):

```
fun rand(range: IntRange): Int {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(range)
}
```

Now you can get a random integer as you would in Ruby without having to first declare a `Random` instance yourself:

```
rand(5..9) // returns 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9
```

Answer (score 12):

**Possible Variation to my [other answer](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) for random chars**

In order to get random `Char`s, you can define an extension function like this

```
fun ClosedRange<Char>.random(): Char = 
       (Random().nextInt(endInclusive.toInt() + 1 - start.toInt()) + start.toInt()).toChar()

// will return a `Char` between A and Z (incl.)
('A'..'Z').random()
```

If you're working with JDK > 1.6, use [`ThreadLocalRandom.current()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-closed-range/index.html) instead of `Random()`.

For kotlinjs and other use cases which don't allow the usage of `java.util.Random`, [this answer](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html) will help.

### Kotlin >= 1.3 multiplatform support for Random

As of  1.3, Kotlin comes with its own multiplatform Random generator. It is described in this [KEEP](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/random.md). You can now directly use the extension as part of the Kotlin standard library without defining it:

```
('a'..'b').random()
```

Answer (score 7):

Building off of [@s1m0nw1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45687695/8073652) excellent answer I made the following changes.

1. (0..n) implies inclusive in Kotlin
2. (0 until n) implies exclusive in Kotlin
3. Use a singleton object for the Random instance (optional)

Code:

```
private object RandomRangeSingleton : Random()

fun ClosedRange<Int>.random() = RandomRangeSingleton.nextInt((endInclusive + 1) - start) + start
```

Test Case:

```
fun testRandom() {
        Assert.assertTrue(
                (0..1000).all {
                    (0..5).contains((0..5).random())
                }
        )
        Assert.assertTrue(
                (0..1000).all {
                    (0..4).contains((0 until 5).random())
                }
        )
        Assert.assertFalse(
                (0..1000).all {
                    (0..4).contains((0..5).random())
                }
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

### Kotlin >= 1.3, multiplatform support for Random

As of 1.3, the standard library provided multi-platform support for randoms, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45687695/8073652) answer.

### Kotlin < 1.3 on JavaScript

If you are working with Kotlin JavaScript and don't have access to `java.util.Random`, the following will work:

```
fun IntRange.random() = (Math.random() * ((endInclusive + 1) - start) + start).toInt()
```

Used like this:

```
// will return an `Int` between 0 and 10 (incl.)
(0..10).random()
```

Answer (score 6):

Examples random in the range [1, 10]

```
val random1 = (0..10).shuffled().last()
```

or utilizing Java Random

```
val random2 = Random().nextInt(10) + 1
```

Comment: Your first answer I like the most. It's a perfect one-liner that does not requre to write any extension functions

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk please don't. `shuffled()` will return a list. Just imagine what would happen if you pass `(0..Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

Comment: @deviant Good point. It's just that I had a use-case where I needed to get random element from the collection.

Answer (score 5):

Another way of implementing s1m0nw1's answer would be to access it through a variable. Not that its any more efficient but it saves you from having to type ().

```
val ClosedRange<Int>.random: Int
    get() = Random().nextInt((endInclusive + 1) - start) +  start
```

And now it can be accessed as such

```
(1..10).random
```

Answer (score 5):

No need to use custom extension functions anymore. [IntRange](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/index.html) has a [`random()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/random.html#random) extension function out-of-the-box now.

```
val randomNumber = (0..10).random()
```

Answer (score 4):

If the numbers you want to choose from are not consecutive, you can use [`random()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/random.html).

Usage:

```
val list = listOf(3, 1, 4, 5)
val number = list.random()
```

Returns one of the numbers which are in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Using a top-level function, you can achieve exactly the same call syntax as in Ruby (as you wish):

```
fun rand(s: Int, e: Int) = Random.nextInt(s, e + 1)
```

Usage:

```
rand(1, 3) // returns either 1, 2 or 3
```

Answer (score 3):

get the next random Int from the random number generator.

```
Random.nextInt()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard method that does this but you can easily create your own using either `Math.random()` or the class `java.util.Random`. Here is an example using the `Math.random()` method:

```
fun random(n: Int) = (Math.random() * n).toInt()
fun random(from: Int, to: Int) = (Math.random() * (to - from) + from).toInt()
fun random(pair: Pair<Int, Int>) = random(pair.first, pair.second)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val n = 10

    val rand1 = random(n)
    val rand2 = random(5, n)
    val rand3 = random(5 to n)

    println(List(10) { random(n) })
    println(List(10) { random(5 to n) })
}
```

This is a sample output:

```
[9, 8, 1, 7, 5, 6, 9, 8, 1, 9]
[5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 6, 8, 6, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin standard lib doesn't provide Random Number Generator API. If you aren't in a multiplatform project, it's better to use the platform api *(all the others answers of the question talk about this solution)*.

**But if you are in a multiplatform context, the best solution is to implement random by yourself in pure kotlin for share the same random number generator between platforms.** It's more simple for dev and testing.

To answer to this problem in my personal project, i implement a pure Kotlin [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). LCG is the algorithm used by `java.util.Random`. Follow this link if you want to use it : 
https://gist.github.com/11e5ddb567786af0ed1ae4d7f57441d4

My implementation purpose `nextInt(range: IntRange)` for you ;).

Take care about my purpose, LCG is good for most of the use cases *(simulation, games, etc...)* but is not suitable for cryptographically usage because of the predictability of this method.

Comment: I'd rather rely on platform specific code than make my own random algorithm. This reminds me a bit about the code for java.util.Random, but it doesn't completely match.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a RNG. In Kotlin you currently need to use the platform specific ones (there isn't a Kotlin built in one). For the JVM it's [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). You'll need to create an instance of it and then call `random.nextInt(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

> **To get a random Int number in Kotlin use the following method**:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom

fun randomInt(rangeFirstNum:Int, rangeLastNum:Int) {
    val randomInteger = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(rangeFirstNum,rangeLastNum)
    println(randomInteger)
}
fun main() {    
    randomInt(1,10)
}


// Result – random Int numbers from 1 to 9
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Below in Kotlin worked well for me:

```
(fromNumber.rangeTo(toNumber)).random()
```

Range of the numbers starts with variable `fromNumber` and ends with variable `toNumber`. `fromNumber` and `toNumber` will also be included in the random numbers generated out of this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension function:

```
infix fun ClosedRange<Float>.step(step: Float): Iterable<Float> {
    require(start.isFinite())
    require(endInclusive.isFinite())
    require(step.round() > 0.0) { "Step must be positive, was: $step." }
    require(start != endInclusive) { "Start and endInclusive must not be the same"}

    if (endInclusive > start) {
        return generateSequence(start) { previous ->
            if (previous == Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY) return@generateSequence null
            val next = previous + step.round()
            if (next > endInclusive) null else next.round()
        }.asIterable()
    }

    return generateSequence(start) { previous ->
        if (previous == Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) return@generateSequence null
        val next = previous - step.round()
        if (next < endInclusive) null else next.round()
    }.asIterable()
}
```

Round Float value:

```
fun Float.round(decimals: Int = DIGITS): Float {
    var multiplier = 1.0f
    repeat(decimals) { multiplier *= 10 }
    return round(this * multiplier) / multiplier
}
```

Method's usage:

```
(0.0f .. 1.0f).step(.1f).forEach { System.out.println("value: $it") }
```

Output:

> value: 0.0 value: 0.1 value: 0.2 value: 0.3 value: 0.4 value: 0.5
>   value: 0.6 value: 0.7 value: 0.8 value: 0.9 value: 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Full source code. Can control whether duplicates are allowed.

```
import kotlin.math.min

abstract class Random {

    companion object {
        fun string(length: Int, isUnique: Boolean = false): String {
            if (0 == length) return ""
            val alphabet: List<Char> = ('a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9') // Add your set here.

            if (isUnique) {
                val limit = min(length, alphabet.count())
                val set = mutableSetOf<Char>()
                do { set.add(alphabet.random()) } while (set.count() != limit)
                return set.joinToString("")
            }
            return List(length) { alphabet.random() }.joinToString("")
        }

        fun alphabet(length: Int, isUnique: Boolean = false): String {
            if (0 == length) return ""
            val alphabet = ('A'..'Z')
            if (isUnique) {
                val limit = min(length, alphabet.count())
                val set = mutableSetOf<Char>()
                do { set.add(alphabet.random()) } while (set.count() != limit)
                return set.joinToString("")
            }

            return List(length) { alphabet.random() }.joinToString("")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a situation where you want to generate key or mac address which is hexadecimal number having digits based on user demand, and that too using android and kotlin, then you my below code helps you:

```
private fun getRandomHexString(random: SecureRandom, numOfCharsToBePresentInTheHexString: Int): String {
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    while (sb.length < numOfCharsToBePresentInTheHexString) {
        val randomNumber = random.nextInt()
        val number = String.format("%08X", randomNumber)
        sb.append(number)
    }
    return sb.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward solution in Kotlin, which also works on KMM:

```
fun IntRange.rand(): Int =
    Random(Clock.System.now().toEpochMilliseconds()).nextInt(first, last)
```

**Seed** is needed for the different random number on each run. You can also do the same for the LongRange.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get a random element from a colletion, use `random()` from kotlin's `_Collections.kt like this:

```
yourCollection.random()
```

or use `randomOrNull()` get null if your collection is empty:

```
yourCollection.randomOrNull()
```

Answer (score -2):

to be super duper ))

```
 fun rnd_int(min: Int, max: Int): Int {
        var max = max
        max -= min
        return (Math.random() * ++max).toInt() + min
    }
```