# How to choose a random color from a list in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, static, jvm

How can I choose **a random color** in **Kotlin** **from a list**? I ***couldn't find anything*** related to this topic...

Thanks.

Comment: could you give more details?

Comment: Yes. So I want to choose a random number from my list in Kotlin and to change my Button background to that random color. Hope that makes sense. Thanks for your comment

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by *generate (...) from a list*. As far as I know, you could *choose* a random color from a list or *generate* one from RGB values, maybe.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear. I mean to choose a random color from a list

Comment: `couldn't find anything` because what you're trying to do is 2 separate tasks. picking a random value from an array and populating an array with colors. it's useful to know how to split up tasks

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a color array and use `random()` func to get random color from it

```
val colors = arrayOf(
     Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"),
     Color.parseColor("#000000"),
     Color.parseColor("#FF8F00"),
     Color.parseColor("#EF6C00"),
     Color.parseColor("#D84315"),
     Color.parseColor("#37474F"),
     //...more
)
val randomColor = colors.random()
```

Or random generate a color

```
val rnd = Random.Default //kotlin.random
val color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256))
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin Random is used as a companion object so this should work. You will get random value between 0 and 255:

```kotlin
val color = Color.argb(255, Random.nextInt(0, 255), Random.nextInt(0, 255), Random.nextInt(0, 255))
```

EDIT:

I saw that you commented and you want to obtain color from the list. Thanks to Kotlin we have a lot of additional functionalities on collections, so you can use `random()` function to obtain random object from the list:

```kotlin
val colors = arrayListOf(color1, color2, color3, color4)
val randomColor = colors.random()
```

Answer (score 0):

Helpful.

**Java**

```
Random rnd = new Random();
paint.setARGB(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
```

**Kotlin**

```
val rnd = Random()
val color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256))
myView.setBackgroundColor(color)
```

[Random Doc Source](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/)

Comment: I have tried this, but this doesn't seem to work in kotlin version 1.4

Comment: I can not create an abstract property of Random() in Kotlin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685026/how-can-i-get-a-random-number-in-kotlin 

Random Implement Problem HelpFul