# get random alphapet without create list of all alphabets

Tags: kotlin

I want to get random alphabet without create list of all alphabets and get random index

I tried this

```
fun getChar(){
    val alphabets = ('a'..'z').toList()
    return alphabets[Random().nextInt(alphabets.size)]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a random number in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685026/how-can-i-get-a-random-number-in-kotlin)

Comment: You can just use `('a'..'z').random()`

Comment: I think you mean a random _letter_.  An [_alphabet_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet) is the _set_ of letters in a language (such as 'a'...'z').

Answer (score 2):

You can use ASCII Character codes. generate a random number from 97 representing a, to 122 representing z, then use `toChar(charCode)` to get the corresponding letter.

also see: [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/)

ALSO as Madhu Bhat said in the comments you can use `('a'..'z').random()` for a more precise way.

Comment: The hard way...

Comment: @Tenfour04 its not that hard really.  I prefer this approach performance wise, although, maybe it doesn't matter