# Why does this call to IntRange.random() in Kotlin cause a stack overflow on godbolt?

Tags: kotlin, godbolt

Does anybody know why this simple code is causing a stack overflow in godbolt?

```
import java.util.Random

fun main()
{
    val randomNumber = (1..6).random()
}
```

[Here it is in action on godbolt using Kotlin 1.6.10](https://godbolt.org/z/fY5sPMM8f).  I get the same error whether including `import java.util.Random` or not:

```
Program stderr

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(ClassLoader.java:665)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:646)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:855)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:753)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:676)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:855)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:753)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:676)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:855)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:753)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:676)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:855)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:753)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:676)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:855)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:753)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:676)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at kotlin.internal.PlatformImplementationsKt.getJavaVersion(PlatformImplementations.kt:87)
    at kotlin.internal.PlatformImplementationsKt.<clinit>(PlatformImplementations.kt:51)
    at kotlin.random.Random.<clinit>(Random.kt:271)
    at ExampleKt.main(example.kt:6)
    at ExampleKt.main(example.kt)
```

I'm brand new to Kotlin, but looks like I'm doing everything right according to Google's own [online tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-create-dice-roller-in-kotlin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-four%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-create-dice-roller-in-kotlin#1) and [this existing SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685026/how-can-i-get-a-random-number-in-kotlin).  Is godbolt misbehaving in this instance, or am I missing something?  Furthermore, I've used nearly identical code in a test app running on an actual Android device and it works no problem...

Comment: Probably threads on godbold are configured with too little memory for stack or there is some other configuration problem there. Your code is fine, you may use official online compiler here: https://pl.kotl.in/fYXdKxH9e

Comment: @marcinj Thanks for the alternative playground! I turned to godbolt because [Google's playground](https://developer.android.com/training/kotlinplayground) isn't working for me either (I see no output). I suspect I need to use Chrome or disable my PiHole. But the playground you've linked is working.

Comment: @yano Why do you expect your code to output anything? From the stack trace, it does seem more like a godbolt bug.

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry I wasn't clear. I mean with Google's playground I simply don't see the output window. I'll put code in for helloWorld and see nothing. When I first go to the page I see a box at the bottom with a spinning icon, then the whole box quickly disappears. I suspect that's the output window that's getting blocked or hidden for some reason, I don't know, most likely localized to my system. I didn't mean I expect the code in my post to output something, of course it doesn't.